# How to `Thread` over lists with unequal lengths?

Tags: list-manipulation

### Motivation

Consider the definition of tensor product of operators like
\begin{equation}
x1\otimes x2 \otimes x3 \cdot y1\otimes y2 \otimes y3=x1 y1\otimes x2 y2\otimes x3y3   
\end{equation}
where $x_i\in A_i$. Intuitively one can imagine a spin chain, and  $x_i$'s are e.g. spin operators acting on different sites of the spin chain.

We can realize it using `NonCommutativeMultiply` and `CircleTimes`

```
NonCommutativeMultiply[arg1_CircleTimes,arg2_CircleTimes]:=
Block[{NonCommutativeMultiply},
Thread[NonCommutativeMultiply[arg1,arg2],CircleTimes]
]
```

Here `Block` is to prevent the evaluation inside `Thread`. The results are desired

```
(x1\[CircleTimes]x2\[CircleTimes]x3)**(y1\[CircleTimes]y2\[CircleTimes]y3)
```

[image]

### Question

Now if we have a bilocal operator $R: H_1\otimes H_2\to H_1\otimes H_2$ acting on two sites (A concrete example of $R$ is the transposition operator $R(x\otimes y)=y\otimes x$), obeying the following rule
\begin{equation}
x1\otimes R \cdot y1\otimes y2 \otimes y3=x1 y1\otimes R(y2 \otimes y3)
\end{equation}

To realize the rule we need threading over lists with unequal lengths.

What I want is like the following examples:

**Example 1**

```
f[g[x1,R,x4],g[y1,y2,y3,y4]]//thread[#,g]&
```

returns

```
g[f[x1,y1],f[R,g[y2,y3]],f[x4,y4]]
```

**Example 2**

```
f[g[x1,R],g[R,y3]]//thread[#,g]&
```

returns unchanged

```
f[g[x1,R],g[R,y3]]
```

**Example 3**

```
f[g[x1,R],g[y1,R]]//thread[#,g]&
```

returns

```
f[g[x1,y1],g[R,R]]
```

That is to say, `R` behaves like a sequcence with `length[R]=2`, and the lists are threaded as possible as they can. Is there a simple way to realize this version of `thread`?

**Example 4**

A more complicated case is like: now introducing a new one `T` behavine like a sequcence with `length[R]=3`,

```
f[g[x1,T],g[y1,R,y4]]//thread[#,g]&
```

returns

```
g[f[x1,y1],f[T,g[R,y4]]]
```

**Example 5**

If the "effective" lengths are unequal, then abort the evalutation

```
f[g[x1,R],g[R]]
```

returns

```
Abort[]
```

since `length@R=2` and `length@{x1,R}=3`;

Comment: I forgot to say the attributes: `SetAttributes[NonCommutativeMultiply,{Flat,OneIdentity}];
SetAttributes[CircleTimes,{Flat,OneIdentity}];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code.**

```
length[_]=1;
insert$dummy[(g_)[x___]]:=g@@Join@@Map[Join[{#},ConstantArray[$dummy,length[#]-1]]&,{x}];
thread[(f_)[(g_)[x___],(g_)[y___]]]:=Map[Thread[#,f]&,Split[Thread[
  f[insert$dummy[g[x]],insert$dummy[g[y]]],g],MemberQ[#2,$dummy]&]]/.{$dummy->Sequence[]}/.{g[s_]:>s};
```

If symbols have length unequal to one, one can specify them like so:

```
length[R]^=2;
length[T]^=3;
```

**Examples.** It works in the examples given by OP:

```
f[g[x1,R,x4],g[y1,y2,y3,y4]]//thread
(* g[f[x1,y1],f[R,g[y2,y3]],f[x4,y4]] *)

f[g[x1,R],g[R,y3]]//thread
(* f[g[x1,R],g[R,y3]] *)

f[g[x1,R],g[y1,R]]//thread
(* g[f[x1,y1],f[R,R]] *)

f[g[x1,T],g[y1,R,y4]]//thread
(* g[f[x1,y1],f[T,g[R,y4]]] *)

f[g[x1,R],g[R]]//thread
(* generates an error *)
```

**Comment.** I will use the 4th example above to indicate how the code works. Here is the sequence of expressions that is generated during the evaluation:

```
f[g[x1,T],g[y1,R,y4]]
-> f[g[x1,T,$dummy,$dummy],g[y1,R,$dummy,y4]] (* insert $dummy *)
-> g[f[x1,y1],f[T,R],f[$dummy,$dummy],f[$dummy,y4]] (* Thread *)
-> g[g[f[x1,y1]],g[f[T,R],f[$dummy,$dummy],f[$dummy,y4]]] (* Split *)
-> g[f[g[x1],g[y1]],f[g[T,$dummy,$dummy],g[R,$dummy,y4]]] (* Thread *)
-> g[f[g[x1],g[y1]],f[g[T],g[R,y4]]] (* drop $dummy *)
-> g[f[x1,y1],f[T,g[R,y4]]]
```

I understand that the code has limitations as it stands, but wanted to keep it simple.