# Multiplying abstract tensors in Mathematica

Tags: symbolic, expression-manipulation, tensors

I want to do an operation like

$$ AA \otimes BB \times AA' \otimes BB' $$

and have

$$AA \times AA' \otimes BB \times BB' $$

without specifying the elements of $AA$s and $BB$s (and so are their primes).

pseudocode would be

```
term1 = TensorProduct[AA1,BB1];
term2 = TensorProduct[AA2,BB2];
term1.term2
```

however this returns:

$$ AA1\otimes BB1 . AA2\otimes BB2$$

Comment: The dot means: contraction over the last index of the left tensor and first index of the right tensor. It seems to me, that is not what you want.

Comment: Yes, that is not what i want, but also `*` or `Times` doesn't do the trick either.... :(

Comment: Your notation is a bit confusing. Why use two capital letters? I.e. is this equivalent to replacing AA by A, BB by B, AA' by A', BB' by B'? The "circled X" is the common symbol for a tensor product, but what type of multiplication is the plain "X" supposed to be? If you were to do this simple case by hand, what type of "x" yields your expected result? You seem to want to distribute across the two terms, with stuff like BB x AA' + AA x BB' = 0; otherwise your identity doesn't seem to hold.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37002/45431) to a similar question help?

Answer (score 1):

```
relations={
        (*CircleTimes[x_,k_?scalarQ*y_.]:>
            k CircleTimes[x,y],
        CircleTimes[k_?scalarQ*x_.,y_]:>
            k CircleTimes[x,y],
        CircleTimes[x_+y_,z_]:>
            CircleTimes[x,z]+CircleTimes[y,z], 
        CircleTimes[z_,x_+y_]:>
            CircleTimes[z,x]+CircleTimes[z,y],*)
        x_CircleTimes**y_CircleTimes:>
            Thread[x**y,CircleTimes]/;Length@x==Length@y    
    };

(*scalarQ[expr_]:=FreeQ[expr,Alternatives[a,b,a1,b1]];*)
```

```
(a⊗b)**(a1⊗b1)//.relations
(*a**a1⊗b**b1*)
```

This is a prototype example of tensor product.

I'd like to use `NonCommutativeMultiply` and `CircleTimes` without internal definitions, which makes the computation more controllable. You can change to `TensorProduct`.

For more complicated examples see [How to `Thread` over lists with unequal lengths?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273356/how-to-thread-over-lists-with-unequal-lengths)

The commented codes implement the linearity of tensor product, and are irrelevant to this example.